# VBA replace collection object with set command causes freeze

Tags: vba, ms-access, collections

I am using Access VBA.  I have a collection that contains class instances.  My code refreshes this collection.  Before updating, I need to clear out the old data.  I have tried various uses of the set command (set col = new collection, set col = nothing etc.)  I have looped through the collection and removed each node one-by-one.  Still, periodically when refreshing this collection the entire program freezes without an error message.  Oddly, if I run other long-running code before the refresh it works fine.  If I pause just before the refresh, it usually works.  It is a non-reoccurring error and I have seen occur in other places in my code where a collection is being over written.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Stop 'used to pause to avoid the error
'https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/20567/clearing-all-items-from-a-collection
Call Module3.ClearCollection(container:=pStNamesRefList)
‘Below are various ways I have tried
' If Not pStNamesRefList Is Nothing Then
' Set pStNamesRefList = Nothing
' End If
' Set pStNamesRefList = New Collection
'FREEZES HERE JUST BEFORE REFRESH
sSql = "SELECT * FROM [" & Me.dbAccessDatabase4ScrubTables & "].StreetNames WHERE StrNameDirty <> '' ORDER BY StrNameDirty, [Original Oder];"
Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql)
Dim node As cStRef
Dim StrNamePreScrub As Variant

Do While Not rs.EOF
     Set node = New cStRef
     node.StrNameDirty = Nz(rs!StrNameDirty)
     node.StrNameClean = Nz(rs!StrNameClean)
     node.StrNamePreScrub = Nz(rs!StrNamePreScrub)
     node.YesNo = Nz(rs!HasNoStreetType)
     node.word = Nz(rs!Rule)
     node.County = Nz(rs!County)
     node.Action = Nz(rs!Continue)
     pStNamesRefList.Add node
     rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Are you running any (weird) code in Class_Initialize? How many nodes are in the collection? I have never had any problems with `Set myCol = New Collection` to remove anything from before.

Comment: How many items are in the Collection you're overwriting?

Comment: There are about 7400 items in the collection.  Each is a class instance containing a few values as shown in the code.  The class definition (cStRef) is reused in several different spots of my code so contains some complex items.   For instance the class itself can hold collections.  But the code that is crashing just populates simple datatype variables